# Setting paths for interactive C-shell

Tags: bash, path, csh

My default shell (on Ubuntu) is bash. However, for a particular programme I need to change to the C-shell. For this I have a .cshrc file set up, however, if I change interactively to the C-shell (I'm using tcsh command for this) I notice that all the bash paths get imported.

Is there a way to stop importing these paths as some of them are incompatible with the programme I need to run. i.e. when I'm in the C-shell environment, I'd like to be able to define everything I need in the .cshrc file so I can control this. I don't want to change my login shell permanently however.

Comment: What do you mean "for a particular program I need to change to the C-shell"? An external program shouldn't care what shell starts it (for example, you can run the same `mv` command from `bash` or `csh`), and if you have a script written in C shell, you can run it with `csh myscript` from `bash`; the two shells don't interact.

Answer (score 4):

Environment variables are always inherited from the parent process[†] so the `.cshrc` will need to manually set or remove any unwanted environment variables

```
setenv PATH /bin:/other/dirs/here:/and/more
unsetenv PS1
```

Note that these are exclusive operations (for which the English "or" is sadly lacking in boolean specificity). `setenv PATH` sets the `PATH` environment variable and `unsetenv PS1` instead removes the unwanted `PS1` environment. Doing `unsetenv PATH` and then `setenv PATH ...` would just waste CPU cycles. Instead, simply set `PATH` to what you want it to be. (Editing `PATH` is a much more complicated task, and will require splitting on `:` and then applying code for each directory element and so forth...why go to all that trouble? Set `PATH` to what it needs to be.)

Or, one can use `env -i csh` to totally blank out the environment in which case the `.cshrc` had better set everything that is necessary (various essential environment variables are set by `login(1)` or equivalent such as `HOME` and so forth):

```
$ env perl -E 'say $ENV{SHELL}'  
/opt/local/bin/mksh
$ env -i perl -E 'say $ENV{SHELL}'

$
```

[†] Bourne shells complicate this by placing shell-only variables such as `PS1` in the same namespace as the rest and then having a boolean (via `export`) that flags those that get passed along via `extern char **environ` to child processes; see the `environ(7)` and `execve(2)` man pages for more details on what is happening without the complication of the shell.

Comment: It sounds like I shouldn't blank out the environment completely. However, how can I use `unsetenv` to remove something from the path imported from bashrc? `unsetenv path=path/I/want/to/remove` doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I have also tried adding the following lines to my .cshrc: `unsetenv PATH

set path=($path /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin )` If I test-run this in the c-shell it clears the path (`echo $PATH` returns `PATH: Undefined variable`). However, when I reset the path, all the paths I had defined in `.bashrc` (and which I'm trying to clear) are added back.

Comment: You would use `unsetenv` to completely unset something not wanted from the parent shell, such as `PS1`. Xor, you would use `setenv PATH=/usr/local/blah:/de/blah:...` to set `PATH` to what it needs to be in `csh`. Also do not mix the `setenv PATH` and `set path=(` forms, they are different, and use different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to stop importing these paths

If you're editing `.cshrc` or `.tcshrc` anyway, you may prefer instead to allow the [environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) you don't want, or whose values you want to change, to be passed to [`tcsh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/tcsh.1.html). Then unset them or modify their values. **That's what [thrig's excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398684/11938) explains how to do.**

However, you *can* do exactly what you've asked for: run `tcsh` without the environment variables you don't want, or give them different values.

If you're running `tcsh` from a [Bourne-style shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Bourne_shell) like [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html) then [you can write `VAR=val` pairs before the command](https://askubuntu.com/a/961781/22949) to set environment variables for that command. For example:

```bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin tcsh
```

This is *not* the same as issuing the assignment as a separate command (by following it with a newline or a `;` character). If you did that, it would not export the variable to the environment of [subprocesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process) like `tcsh`, and the assignment would remain even after the next command were done running.

You can set multiple environment variables this way, too:

```bash
BAR=barval PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin tcsh
```

Observe that the environment variable remains unchanged for subsequent commands run in `bash`:

```
ek@Io:~$ echo "$LANG"
en_US.UTF-8
ek@Io:~$ LANG=C tcsh -c 'echo "$LANG"'
C
ek@Io:~$ echo "$LANG"
en_US.UTF-8
```

---

You can assign the empty string to an environment variable the same way:

```bash
FOO= tcsh
```

However, that's not the same thing as removing the variable entirely from the environment. To do that, you can use the [`env`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/env.1.html) command with the `-u` option:

```bash
env -u FOO tcsh
```

You can also *set* environment variables with `env`:

```bash
env PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin tcsh
```

You don't usually *need* to do that from `bash`, though, since `bash` supports the `VAR=val` syntax.

You can set multiple environment variables with `env` and also unset variables, all in a single command. This is to say that you do *not* need to chain `env` commands. For example, you can use:

```bash
env -u FOO BAR=barval PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin tcsh
```

The actual command `env` runs begins with its first non-option argument that contains no `=` sign.